# My snapping works in Firefox only, any legal code?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I'm learning JS (think I'm not too old to learn) and coding app for drawing electronics at: http://3lectronics.com/draw/Atarado-Draw1.html

The most powerful help I can get is here, because of many great guys sharing knowledge. I stacked cause of 20x20px snapping to grid because I found some hacky (obviously) way to make those snapping. It is working only with Firefox and Seamonkey...code:

```
function ev_canvas (ev) {
if (ev.layerX || ev.layerX == 0) { // Firefox
  x2 = (ev.layerX /2).toFixed(-1) *2 ;
  y2 = (ev.layerY /2).toFixed(-1) *2 ;
} else if (ev.offsetX || ev.offsetX == 0) { // Opera
  x2 = ev.offsetX;
  y2 = ev.offsetY;
}
```

It works excellent (you can try), but other browsers disobey to run it. I found that Chrome doesn't like negative value in .toFixed(), and without this it works, but I don't have snapping...
Any idea....Thanx.

Comment: Were you trying to link this:
http://www.3lectronics.com/electronics-layout/Atarado-Draw1.html

Comment: legal code? What in the world does that mean. Call the cops!!

Comment: @epascarello: He's simply ahead of our times. There will come a time when writing "bad" code will be illegal (exactly like now it's illegal to build your own electric plant or plumbing or car). Only validated software by certified people will be allowed to exist (and of course programmers will not be allowed to decline responsibilities about it - e.g. one will go to jail for not writing a code coverage test suite). It's not this way yet because we're still in the barbarian age of self-proclaimed experts...

Comment: @6502, guess I better practice holding onto my soap.

Comment: Your comment is excellent just as your solving code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) is only supported between 0 and 20 in Chrome

Another way to round to the 10's place would be to divide by 10, round, and than multiply by 10.

```
var x2 = Math.round(ev.layerX /20) *20 ;
```

Not sure what is up with the `*2` `/2` you have going on, but I left it in there.

Comment: It's because he wants to round to 20, not 10.

Comment: Epascarello it works now in Chrome, Opera, Midori....
Thank you very much indeed. BTW /20)*20 have to stay otherwise it won't work.